# Use ModalPopupExtender with datalist and collection pager

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist, modalpopupextender

I have a search button in my page. When I click the button, a paged datalist will show up
with result. I want to use modalPopupExtender with Datalist and collection pager. Is it possible ? Here is the code i tried but it doesn't work :

```
<asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="Label1_ModalPopupExtender" runat="server" CancelControlID="btThoat"
    DynamicServicePath="" Enabled="True" PopupControlID="Panel1" TargetControlID="Label5">
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
    <div style="margin-left: 20px; padding-top: 50px">
        <asp:Label ID="lbl_CS" runat="server" Text="Ca sĩ" ForeColor="#FF33CC" Font-Size="18"
            Visible="True"></asp:Label>
        <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CC9966"
            BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" GridLines="Both" RepeatColumns="4"
            OnItemDataBound="DataList1_ItemDataBound">
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" ForeColor="#330099" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#FFFFCC" />
            <ItemStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#330099" />
            <ItemTemplate>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 10px">
                            <asp:RadioButton ID="rd_CS" runat="server" GroupName="Casi" Text='<%# Eval("MaCS")%>'
                                AutoPostBack="False"></asp:RadioButton>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 75px">
                            <asp:Image ID="Img_Casi" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("Hinhanh")%>' Width="75px"
                                Height="75px" BorderColor="#66FF33" />
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 50px">
                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_Ten" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("TenCS")%>'></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 40px">
                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_Ngaysinh" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Ngaysinh")%>'></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <SelectedItemStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#663399" />
        </asp:DataList>
        <cc2:CollectionPager ID="CollectionPager1" runat="server" MaxPages="1000" PagingMode="QueryString"
            BackNextDisplay="Buttons" QueryStringKey="Datalist1">
        </cc2:CollectionPager>
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

Code in c#:

```
bool Checkcs()
    {
        string cs = "select MaCS, Quocgia, TenCS, Hinhanh, Thongtin, cast(convert(char(11), Ngaysinh, 113) as char) as Ngaysinh from casi where tencs like N'%" + txt_CS.Text + "%'";
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cs, cnn);
        dtSP = new DataTable();
        cnn.Open();
        da.Fill(dtSP);
        cnn.Close();
        CollectionPager1.PageSize = 8;
        CollectionPager1.DataSource = dtSP.DefaultView;
        CollectionPager1.BindToControl = DataList1;
        DataList1.DataSource = CollectionPager1.DataSourcePaged;
        DataList1.DataBind();
        Label1_ModalPopupExtender.Show();
        if (dtSP.Rows.Count != 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

protected void img_CheckCS_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        Checkcs();
    }
```

If it's impossible. Is there another way to do it ? If it's possible. Can you show me an example code ? Any help would be great.

Comment: Nothings Impossible here in programming. Perhaps we have workarounds and wayouts. Even most of the things are already done somewhere else, you just need to hit it..

Comment: Yes It Possible. What problem you faced in this

Comment: @VigneshKumar I tried the code above but nothing show up.It would be great if you show me an example code.

Answer (score 0):

This is Sample. Please refer with this

.modalBackground {
        background-color: Gray;
        filter: alpha(opacity=80);
        opacity: 0.8;
        z-index: 10000;
    }

```
.modalPopupCss {
    background-color: white;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #0066B3;
    padding: 3px;
}
```

**ASPX**

```
 <div>
            <asp:ModalPopupExtender BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" ID="Label1_ModalPopupExtender" CancelControlID="Button2" runat="server" Enabled="True" PopupControlID="Panel1" TargetControlID="lbl_CS"></asp:ModalPopupExtender>
            <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" CssClass="modalPopupCss" runat="server">
                <div style="margin-left: 20px; padding-top: 50px">
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_CS" runat="server" Text="" ForeColor="#FF33CC" Font-Size="18" Visible="True"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
                    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
                    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Close" />
                </div>
            </asp:Panel>

            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

**Aspx.Cs**

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       dt.Columns.Add("ID");
        dt.Columns.Add("Name");
        dt.Columns.Add("State");
     }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add("1", "Vignesh", "True");
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        Label1_ModalPopupExtender.Show();

    }
```

Comment: it worked, but when i clicked the next page in collection pager. the modalpopupextender disapear. Can you append collection pager in your example code ?

Comment: when ever page reload, modal popup window will disappear. so you need to use modelpopup.Show() method

Comment: Can i reload only the panel ?

Comment: I think you can't do so